# This error for trial version: Your installation of LiteSpeed Web Server does not have LiteMage Cache

Tags: magento, litespeed

I was testing a trial version of litespeed for my magento.
I did all installation and configuration steps. but I got this message in litespeed admin page:

> "Your installation of LiteSpeed Web Server does not have LiteMage Cache enabled. Please make sure your LiteSpeed license includes the LiteMage cache module, and LiteMage is turned on in the .htaccess file in the root directory of your Magento installation."

I set litemage on in htaccess and other things!

Does trial version of litespeed has litemage enabled ?

By the way, default port is `8088` (set this in installation), (port 80 was busy), is this problem?

**Or do I have to install magento at path: `/usr/local/lsws/DEFAULT/html` or some where like there? (now magento are running by apache and at `/var/www/html/magento123`)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Apache is still running, so Magento is running through Apache. If  you are on plesk, please follow this [wiki](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:plesk:installation-12) to make LiteSpeed run properly first.

Comment: I turned off apache and set litespeed in port 80. but got 404 error for my website. do I have to move to somewhere else from /var/www/html/magento1 ?

Comment: You will need to adjust the path for the default vhost inside of LSWS if you are not using apache configuration to point the document root to `/var/www/html/magento1`

Comment: is there any where to explain such this configs?
I did not find it.